# Error when I push and build from GitHub to docker hub unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, daemon, azure-pipelines-yaml

After I fixed the docker program and dockerfile path. A new error shown.

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon.

My teammate try to help me fix it but still having the same error. I try to find the solution online but all are related to VM but we only have a self hosted agent at GitHub. Which doesn't run on like local machine.

Error message

```
unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

The process '/home/vscode/azure-pipelines/_work/_tool/docker-stable/17.9.0-ce/x64/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Code

```
  - task: Docker@2

    displayName : Login to Docker Hub

    inputs:

        command: login

        containerRegistry: Docker_Hub #fypproject #dockerRegistryServiceConnection1 #

  - task: DockerInstaller@0

    displayName: Docker Installer

    inputs:

        dockerVersion: 17.09.0-ce

        releaseType: stable

  - script: |

      sudo apt-get update

      sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

    displayName: install docker engine

  - task: Docker@2

    displayName: Build and Push

    inputs:

        command: buildAndPush

        repository:   vampurr/newimage # username/contosoRepository for DockerHub

        Dockerfile: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
```

What we had try is to add the script to install the daemon.

What we are trying to do is to push the image from GitHub to DockerHub.
I code the codes at gitspace and push it to GitHub. Which will run the azure pipeline and tigger GitHub agent.

Comment: At what step do you get that error?

Comment: i think the code is fine since when i checked it from the azure devops web it didnt show any red bars. 
this the whole error from what azure devops give when run the pipeline.

/home/vscode/azure-pipelines/_work/_tool/docker-stable/17.9.0-ce/x64/docker inspect mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:bullseye
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
[]
##[error]Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: ##[error]The process '/home/vscode/azure-pipelines/_work/_tool/docker-stable/17.9.0-ce/x64/docker' failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please answer my question.

Comment: at the Build and Push stage

Comment: is able to run to the last line of code then it shows that error. Since in the azure devops it doesnt show any line error

Comment: @DanielMann do you know how to fix it?